# The grammar behind "ていて+Adj" pattern

Tags: grammar

Today I came across this sentence: "見ていて難しくない？"

That question was used to ask an actor about his own movie. And when I used Google Translate it gave me this translation: "Isn't it difficult to watch?"

When I first saw it, I interpreted it from what I know of the て form usage, like "After watching it, difficult don't you think?" but I wasn't so sure so I had to check Google Translate for that result.

I tried some other examples that I made up myself like "聞いていて良くない？" or "やっていて簡単じゃない？" and they all resulted in a translation that has the pattern of "Isn't it ... to ...?"

So is my interpretation correct and this is just a way Japanese people use to express the idea "Isn't it ... to ...?" or it's an actual grammatical structure that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Looks like google's translate close to truth. Bust examples to understand this sentence are `毎日筋トレやっていて、大変じゃない？` or `Tシャツだけで散歩していて、寒くない？` `Isn't it difficult to do exercises everyday` or `isn't it cold to walk only in a t-shirt`

Comment: @rzlvmp Adding a comma makes it way more understandable to me though. It seems to me that it's just like two clauses joined together by a て form. Can I put it this way without changing the meaning? `毎日筋トレやっているのは大変じゃない？`

Comment: I don't think this is some set grammatical construct, but rather simply a reordering of the sentence structure for emphasis.

Comment: 見ていて難しくない may mean something like "While watching it, don't you feel it's difficult", but we need more context to answer a question like this. Please provide three of four **original** sentences before this.